# SSIS Debug mode flagged Package Execution Completed while task is still running

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am using SSIS extension 3.16 in VS 2019. I have the following SSIS package

[image]

I don't know why when I run it with Debug Mode,. It flagged "Package Execution Completed before all tasks turning green after less than 1 minutes execution.

I have clicked into in those  data flows,  some indicated data have transferred.

[image]
[image]

While some was still pending

[image]
[image]

Queries under those unfinished task is very big and should take very long time to finish (20 mins +).

Could someone share me some light on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work out the reason was there was a comment on some of those queries. Once done it is all good!